# Access caller function context not passing it

Tags: javascript, scope

How can I access caller context, if it was called from another function or even frame?
Example 1. Is it possible in general?

```
var aaa = function(){
    (function(){console.log(ab)}).call(arguments.callee.caller); //fail
}
function bbb(){
    var ab = 'fff'; //defined in this function's context
    aaa();
}
```

Example 2.

```
<html>
    function someFunction(){
        //description on bottom
    }
    <iframe>
        function() bbb(){parent.someFunction();}
        bbb();
    </iframe>
</html>
```

Can I get the caller function's Window object without passing it directly to someFunction? I can have multiple iframes, and all of them will call someFunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible in general?

You can get a reference to the caller function, but you can never access its local variables outside of that function.

> Can I get the caller function's Window object without passing it directly to someFunction?

No. There is no exposed relation between a function object and the `window` object of the environment the function was defined in. The `window` object is part of the function's scope chain, but you cannot access the scope chain.

---

Be explicit, pass whatever the function needs to know to the function (*dependency injection*). It also makes your functions easier to test.

Comment: Actual problem is directly connected with example 2.
Your answer is full, and I have to rewrite code to solve my problems.

Comment: Be explicit, pass whatever the function needs to know to the function (*dependency injection*). It also makes your code easier to test.